# Hide taxonomy term in specific node form

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a select list of taxonomy terms, all terms are needed for searching in views, but I don't need for insert new content. I wrote a custom module, which Hook should I use to hide some terms of my select list?

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter.
 */
function my_module_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $vocabulary_machine_name = 'my_vocabulary'; // Makes the search faster.
  $term_names = array(
    'Term 1',
    'Term 2',
    'Term 3',
  );

  foreach ($term_names as $term_name) {
    $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, $vocabulary_machine_name);
    unset($form['my_field']['#options'][array_pop($term)->tid]);
  }
}
```